# Segmentation in QuickSort

Tags: c, algorithm, segmentation-fault, quicksort

I'm getting a segmentation fault:11 when I try to run this QuickSort, but it compiles fine.  I'm running it with a driver, which is why I use quicksort() and quicksortR().  What's causing the segmentation?

```
/*  -------- Quick sort stuff starts here --------- */
int partition(int array[], int start, int stop) {
    int compars = 0;
    int pivot = array[stop];
    int i = start - 1;
    for (int j = start; j <= stop - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            int temp = array[j];//swaps values of i and j
            array[j] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
        }
        compars++;
    }
    int temp = array[i + 1];
    array[i + 1] = array[stop];
    array[stop] = temp;
    return compars;
}

int quickSortR(int array[], int start, int stop) {
    int compars = 0;
    int mid = array[stop];
    if (start < stop) {
        compars = compars + partition(array, start, stop);
        quickSortR(array, start, mid - 1);
        quickSortR(array, mid+1, stop);
    }
    return compars;
}

int quickSort(int array[], int n) {
    return quickSortR(array, 0, n);
}

/*  ----------- end quick sort stuff ----------------- */
```

Comment: I suggest you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a *debugger* to catch crashes lite this.

Comment: `int quickSort(int array[], int n)`.What is `n` here? If number of elements in `array`, then you go out of bounds at `int mid = array[stop];`

Comment: Yes, n is the size of the array.

Comment: `int mid = array[stop];`.. I think that `mid` can't use like  `quickSortR(array, start, mid-1);`

Comment: 'I'm getting a segmentation fault:11 when I try to run this QuickSort, but it compiles fine' - this is normal behaviour for software that is only half-devloped, ie. written and built but not tested and debugged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `quicksort` with the number of elements of the array as the `stop` argument, but you initialize the pivot as `int pivot = array[stop];`.  You are reading past the end of the array. Undefined behavior.

There are probably other problems in the code, but this alone explains the crash.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting a segmentation fault:11 when I try to run this QuickSort, but it compiles fine

Please note: program compiling means compiler understands what you want your program to do. In no way compiler checks if what your program does makes any sense whatsoever. 
If it knew what you want to do why wouldn't it write the program itself?